# Replace before and after string in vim

Tags: xml, vim

I have a large XML file that has essential information commented out for whatever dumb reason the author decided to do it.

It's similar to the following:

```
<book id="cat2" type="t" group="1234">  <!-- Group Name -->
    <book id='ABC123' type='s'/>   <!-- NameOfBookHere -->
    <book id='etc456' type='s'/>   <!-- Harry Potter -->
    <book id='XYZ234' type='s'/>  <!-- Jurassic Park --> //Notice variable space before the comment tag.
</book>
```

I'd like to be able to do a replace based on the first replace. Here's what I tried.

1. I need to get rid of the beginning comment tag. I tried: `:%s/\/> \+<!-- / name="`
2. I try another similar one for tags that aren't self closing `:%s/> \+<!-- / name="`
3. Then replace the remaining: `%s/ -->/"\/>`

The results are something like this:

```
<book id="cat2" type="t" group="1234" name="Group Name"/>
    <book id='ABC123' type='s' name="NameOfBookHere"/>
    <book id='etc456' type='s' name="Harry Potter"/>
    <book id='XYZ234' type='s' name="Jurassic Park"/>
</book>
```

Unfortunately, this affects `<book>` tags with attribute `group` in it which aren't self closing.

Which means I'm left with thousands of self-closing `<book>`tags that aren't supposed to be self closing xml tags. It's not feasible to remove them manually of course.

Is there a way I can do another replace based on the lines that were affected by the first replace? Or is there another solution to my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:%s#\v(\>|/\>)\s*\<!--\s*(.{-})\s*--\># name="\2"\1#
```

With:

- `%s` : substitute on all lines
- `#` : alternate separator (especially useful when editing xml)
- `\v` : use VeryMagic mode (see `:h magic`)
- `(\>|/\>)` : capture either `>` or `/>`
- `\s*` : 0-n whitespaces
- `\<!--\s*(.{-})\s*--\>` : capture the text in the comment (`{-}` is vim's non-greedy `*` (similar to `*?` is other languages))
- `#` : end of regex
- `name="\2"\1` : insert 'name="comment_text"' and end with the separator you first captured

**EDIT:**

As Peter Rincker said you can use the 'zero or one' (usually `\=`/`\?`, or `=`/`?` if very magic is on) quantifier in the first group to indicate the possible presence of `/` :

```
:%s#\v(/?\>)\s*\<!--\s*(.{-})\s*--\># name="\2"\1#
```

Comment: No need for alternation in that first capture group. Just use `\=` (using `magic`). `\=` matches 0 or 1 as many as possible. Similar to Perl's `?`. e.g. `:%s#\v(/=\>)...`